# How to view sections breaks in version 1910 of Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to view sections breaks in version 1910 (build 12130.20390) of Microsoft Word?

(According to some research, it is supposed to be located in the Home menu but it seems to have moved somewhere else. Searching also gets me many article on how to insert section breaks but not many on how to visualise them.)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It is still actually in the "Home" menu but it is not a checkbox anymore. There is a sign called a "pilcrow" which looks like de mirror "P" stuck to a "T" which toggles the displays of all hidden characters in document (not only section breaks).